# Regex Javascript to catch string

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using this regex  `^(?:foo|bar)+|(.+)$` to catch string different from 'foo' or 'bar' but it catches string only after foo or bar and not at beginning. For example it catches `ba` in string `foobarfooba` but doesn't catch `ba` in string `bafoobarfoo`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aS5eX9/2)

Comment: I suppose you didn't mean to use those `^`  and `$` anchors?

Answer (score 1):

Because you used the start of a line anchor. Removing the start of the line anchor also won't work for you. So I suggest you to use the below regex.

```js
var s = "bafoobar";
var re = /foo|bar|((?:(?!foo|bar).)+)/gm;
alert(re.exec(s)[1])
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vZ7nB0/1)

Comment: Ok it is perfect ,but I don't understand why with `var patt = new RegExp("foo|bar|((?:(?!foo|bar).)+)");

var res = patt.test(string);


console.log(res)//true; and string = foobarfoobarbarfoo` why res is true?

Comment: You need to use exec function to get the value from group index 1.

Comment: This is result of exec `["foo", undefined, index: 0, input: "foobarfoobarbarfoo"]`.Why it match foo ?

Comment: It does matching foo or bar but captures only the text other than foo or bar. Check my update..

Comment: Your exec solution doesn't work ad example with `foobarba`

Comment: regex is correct. You have to do somethinbg with exec. Than is append each match into an array and printoput only th text ie, not of undefined.

Comment: Yes regex is correct, but with foobarba exec returns` ["foo", undefined, index: 0, input: "foobarba"] `? There is no 'ba'

Comment: see it shows you the index 0 not index 1. have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/a/432503/3297613

Comment: Problem is that it matches also foo and bar. It has to match only word different from them like ba. So the index of exec change everytime depending where ba is.